# Specialized Powerset Requirement

Tags: python, regex, powerset

Let's say I have compiled five regular expression patterns and then created five Boolean variables:

```
a =  re.search(first, mystr)
b =  re.search(second, mystr)
c =  re.search(third, mystr)
d = re.search(fourth, mystr)
e = re.search(fifth, mystr)
```

I want to use the Powerset of (a, b, c, d, e) in a function so it finds more specific matches first then falls through.   As you can see, the Powerset (well, its list representation) should be sorted by # of elements descending.

Desired behavior:

```
 if a and b and c and d and e:
     return 'abcde' 
 if a and b and c and d:
     return 'abcd'
 [... and all the other 4-matches ]
 [now the three-matches]
 [now the two-matches]
 [now the single matches]
 return 'No Match'  # did not match anything
```

Is there a way to utilize the Powerset programmatically and ideally, tersely, to get this function's behavior?

Comment: As in `r = [a, b, c, d, e]; n = sum[(1 if x else 0) for x in r]`, with `n` then the number of matching expressions?

Comment: dhke, your solution is good, but in addition to the number of matches n, i would also like to know which of the elements a,b,c,d,e matched.  As noted below, these variables are Match Objects so I am having trouble retrieving their literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`powerset()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=powerset#recipes) generator function recipe in the `itertools` documentation like this:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
from pprint import pprint
import re

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

mystr   = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
first   = "a"
second  = "B"  # won't match, should be omitted from result
third   = "c"
fourth  = "d"
fifth   = "e"

a = 'a' if re.search(first, mystr) else ''
b = 'b' if re.search(second, mystr) else ''
c = 'c' if re.search(third, mystr) else ''
d = 'd' if re.search(fourth, mystr) else ''
e = 'e' if re.search(fifth, mystr) else ''

elements = (elem for elem in [a, b, c, d, e] if elem is not '')
spec_ps = [''.join(item for item in group)
              for group in sorted(powerset(elements), key=len, reverse=True)
                  if any(item for item in group)]

pprint(spec_ps)
```

Output:

```
['acde',
 'acd',
 'ace',
 'ade',
 'cde',
 'ac',
 'ad',
 'ae',
 'cd',
 'ce',
 'de',
 'a',
 'c',
 'd',
 'e']
```

Comment: This works, and since my mystr variable contained potentially repeating elements, I took the set(spec_ps) to report on what I needed, the conditions that matched.

Comment: You could create the `set` directly from by making the list comprehension a generator function. i.e. `spec_ps = set(''.join(item for item in group) ...)` to remove any repeated elements. The only problem may be that you'll lose the ordering the list implicitly contains. Also if you don't need the results ordered, there's no reason to use `sorted()` either.

Comment: You should also note that this suppresses the empty set, which is technically one of the combinations in a [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). This should be an easy thing to add, if you wished.

Answer (score 0):

First, those aren't booleans; they're either match objects or `None`. Second, going through the power set would be a terribly inefficient way to go about this. Just stick each letter in the string if the corresponding regex matched:

```
return ''.join(letter for letter, match in zip('abcde', [a, b, c, d, e]) if match)
```

Comment: My variables as defined:  a, b, c, d, e  can be used as Booleans in that I can say    if a:  # this executes if there was a regex match, this is the sense in which I was using Boolean.